# Implementar datatable en Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, datatables

Tengo el siguiente Modelo:

```
class Coin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    short_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=6)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transaction_fee = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    market_cap = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    volume = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    circulating = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
    change = models.FloatField(default=0.0,blank=True)
    cid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, unique=True)
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

Y lo pinto así:

```
<table id="table_all_coins" class="table">
  <thead class=" text-primary">
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Short Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Market Cap
    </th>
    <th>
      Price
    </th>
    <th>
      volume (24h)
    </th>
    <th>
      Circulating Supply
    </th>
    <th>
      Change (24h)
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for coin in Coins %}
    <tr class="{{coin.cid}}">
      <td id="name">
        {{coin.name}}
      </td>
      <td class="short_name">
        {{coin.short_name}}
      </td>
      <td class="market_cap">
        {{coin.market_cap}}€
      </td>
      <td class="price">
        {{coin.price}}€
      </td>
      <td class="volume">
        {{coin.volume}}€
      </td>
      <td class="circulating">
        {{coin.circulating}} {{coin.short_name}}
      </td>
      <td class="change">
        {{coin.change}}%
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Me genera una tabla como la siguiente:

[image: Imagen de la tabla pintada en html]

Luego, actualizo la tabla con el siguiente método AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=EUR", function(data){
  {% for coin in my_coins %}
  var market_cap = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['quotes']['EUR']['market_cap']+'€'
  var price = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['quotes']['EUR']['price']+'€'
  var volume = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['quotes']['EUR']['volume_24h']+'€'
  var circulating = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['total_supply']+' {{coin.short_name}}'
  var change = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['quotes']['EUR']['percent_change_24h']+'%'
  $("#table_my_coins .{{coin.cid}} .market_cap")[0].innerText = market_cap
  $("#table_my_coins .{{coin.cid}} .price")[0].innerText = price
  $("#table_my_coins .{{coin.cid}} .volume")[0].innerText = volume
  $("#table_my_coins .{{coin.cid}} .circulating")[0].innerText = circulating
  $("#table_my_coins .{{coin.cid}} .change")[0].innerText = change
  {% endfor %}
  {% for coin in Coins %}
  var market_cap = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['quotes']['EUR']['market_cap']+'€'
  var price = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['quotes']['EUR']['price']+'€'
  var volume = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['quotes']['EUR']['volume_24h']+'€'
  var circulating = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['total_supply']+' {{coin.short_name}}'
  var change = data['data']['{{coin.cid}}']['quotes']['EUR']['percent_change_24h']+'%'
  $("#table_all_coins .{{coin.cid}} .market_cap")[0].innerText = market_cap
  $("#table_all_coins .{{coin.cid}} .price")[0].innerText = price
  $("#table_all_coins .{{coin.cid}} .volume")[0].innerText = volume
  $("#table_all_coins .{{coin.cid}} .circulating")[0].innerText = circulating
  $("#table_all_coins .{{coin.cid}} .change")[0].innerText = change
  {% endfor %}
  });
setInterval(ajax, 60000);
});
```

**Quiero saber cómo pasar eso a un Datatable de Bootstrap o de otro tipo** que me permita ordenar por columnas y las funcionalidades básicas.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: te recomiendo usar esto: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Como dice Tegito descarga ese plugin, agregalo a tu proyecto y en un archivo js llama a lo siguiente, tenes que tener jquery tambien, mira esa pagina que tiene otros ejemplos o distintas configuraciones para amoldar a tu tabla                                     
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#id de tu tabla').DataTable();
} );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te dejare aqui un ejemplo basico de datatables con django.

1. Descargar los archivos necesarios de datables.net(css  y js)
2. Incluir dichos archivos a tu carpeta static
3. incluir tus css y js de datatables a tu template

algo asi:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'DataTables/dataTables.min.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'DataTables/dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>
```

con esas lineas agregarias los css y js descargados de datatables.
en mi caso mi carpeta se llama DataTables, cambiala como la tengas tu.

**ahora en el views.py**

```
from django.template import loader
def Ejemplo(request):
    
    template = loader.get_template('miTemplate.html')
    context = {
        'ejemplo_list':Ejemplo.objects.all(),
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

no te olvides de importar tu models.

**en tu template:**

```
       <table id="table_ejemploList" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr bgcolor="#bee5eb">
                        <th class="text-center">#</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="30%">Nombre</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="40%">Correo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                
                {% for ejemplo in ejemplo_list  %}
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                        <td>{{ ejemplo.nombre }}</td>
                        <td>{{ ejemplo.correo }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

si lo realizas asi no estara del todo implementado el datatables, debemos instanciarlo, podemos realizar directamente en el template, es recomendable usar un archivo externo js para todo lo que sea javascript, jquery, ajax..etc..

lo instanciamos en base al id que colocamos en table en este caso(table_ejemploList)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_ejemploList').DataTable();
} );
```

con eso podrias ver algo asi:
[image: ejemplo posible]
datatables tiene un sin fin de posibilidades y plugins. te sugiero leer la documentacion:

[Documentacion](https://datatables.net/manual/)

Espero te sirva y suerte

Comment: si te fijas uso {{ forloop.counter }} me permite mostrar o enumerar cada uno de los elementos de la tabla si deseas lo usas o sino no..!!

Comment: Gracias! esta tarde lo pruebo

Comment: ¿Sabrías decirme cómo actualizo los campos con la petición ajax que tengo?

Comment: cuando tu ingresar o insertas un regstro en tu base de datos,, autimaticamente la tabla se refresca... trae los nuevos registros